# How to limit log from certain package when running gradlew test?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, gradle, build.gradle

I have set `testLogging.showStandardStreams = true` in `build.gradle`, but it is printing log message from all classes, including Spring boot classes. But I want only log statements written in my test classes should print.
If I have package called `org.example.test`, can I set somewhere the package in build.gradle, or do we have some other property?

Currently it print something like this and I don't want first 2 lines:

```
2021-10-11 18:35:05.575+0530 [] 2424@HOSTNAME [Test worker] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring TestDispatcherServlet ''
2021-10-11 18:35:05.574+0530 [] 2424@HOSTNAME [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#0-299] WARN  org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
2021-10-11 18:35:05.604+0530 [] 2424@HOSTNAME [Test worker] INFO  com.exmple.test - --------S--------
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to check [gradle offical doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/logging.html) for more about logger.

There are 6 types of logs and you can add parameter to get it:

- ERROR for Error messages ( will always be shown )
- QUIET for Important information messages ( add -q )
- WARNING for Warning messages ( add -w )
- LIFECYCLE for Progress information messages
- INFO for Information messages (add -i )
- DEBUG for Debug messages (add -d )

For example if you want to get the debug , you type `gradle build -d` and so on .